# 1/5 host is being overloaded when using Apache Http client & Pooling connection manager to interact with the services

Tags: overloading, apache-httpclient-4.x

We have service A and Service B, B has 5 hosts which is being called using domain name from Service A. MaxTotal is set as 100 and DefaultMaxPerRoute as 50. No keep alive strategy and no explicit close defined. 1/5 hos is Service B is always loaded and other services are comparatively free. From A to B there are very frequent calls as well. I have read as poolConnectionManger will reuse the connection, would that be the possible causes of this overload. What would be possible solutions? In Service B header there is no keep alive.

Will custom Keep alive will work or should need a explicit close? But if close is being used how the pooling and parallel connection will work? I can not have another load balancer between these two as this two are purely internal.

Comment: Assuming the server doing the DNS load balancing has been configured correctly (perhaps worth testing manually), you could try adjusting the TTL for how long the domain name is associated with a particular IP: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html  If only 1 instance of Service A is being hit and Service B has the same associated IP for 30 to 60 seconds, then such a problem could occur.